# Making the best of a bad "checksum" algorithm

Tags: embedded, serial-port, driver, checksum

I'm working on an existing driver that controls an 8-bit MCU over a serial port.  There are many different flavors of firmware for the MCU but they all share a common method of trying to ensure link integrity.  This method is not very robust and I am looking for ideas about how the driver could modify its behavior to get the most out of it.

Commands are gcode with a line number and a checksum:

```
N3 T0*57
N4 G92 E0*67
N5 G28*22
N6 G1 F1500.0*82
N7 G1 X2.0 Y2.0 F3000.0*85
N8 G1 X3.0 Y3.0*33
```

The line number must be sequential (but can be reset with `M110`).  If the checksum doesn't match or the line number is out of sequence the firmware will reply `Resend: nnn` where `nnn` is the last successful `N` plus 1.  The "checksum" is extremely primitive:

```
        // Calc checksum.
        byte checksum = 0;
        byte count = 0;
        while(instruction[count] != '*')
                checksum = checksum^instruction[count++];
```

The main problem is that the primary error mechanism is *dropped bytes* due to interrupts being held off leading to overflows in the 1-byte MCU FIFO.  The actual serial bus is a few cm between an FTDI (or similar) USB serial bridge and the MCU, so bit errors are unlikely.  I've never observed a bit error in a reply from the firmware.

As you can see, the algorithm above would detect one dropped byte, but if you dropped two of the same byte (anywhere!) the result would still match.  Thus `F3000.0` (feedrate 3000mm/min) could be transmuted to `F30.0` and still match.  Plus, the character set is very small so certain bits are never going to be involved.

Is there anything the driver can do to make a given line more robust?

- Add or drop trailing (or even leading) zeroes
- Add or drop spaces
- Re-order words (`X1 Y1` is the same as `Y1 X1`)
- Add or drop spaces
- Make "insignificant" modifications to values within some tolerance (eg `F2999.9` instead of `F3000`)
- Reset the line number to get some specific `N` for a given line
- Break a single command into multiple equivalent commands (eg `G1 X2` becomes `G1 X1` `G1 X2` assuming X=0 initially)
- Eliminate (or add) superfluous words (eg `T0` is meaningless for most commands, and if you send `F3000` once it is implied in the future so it can be optionally sent or not)

If I believe that the firmware drops bytes in groups then the most important thing could be to avoid back-to-back duplicates like `00` which would (if dropped together) be invisible.

Comment: To be clear - you have no control or ability to modify the 8-bit MCU's firmware to use a different checksum and/or command line interpreter?

Comment: It's all open source, so that's definitely a possibility.  It would be nice to make the driver as robust as possible for the many instances of firmware out there.  (Although the better modification to the firmware would be better serial comms management!)

Comment: The tolerance modification idea is scary!  On a complex sequence the tolerances might stack-up, and customers will find that parts made on your machines never seem to quite fit!

Comment: Another thing about the tolerance modification idea: "F2999.9" has the same problem as "F3000" - three '9' characters in a row is just as bad as three '0' characters in a row.  You'd have to do something like "F2989.9" to avoid dropping 2 of the same characters in a row.  Seems like a lot of error to introduce.  And it's still subject to dropping two nines undetected, though non-sequential dropped characters might be more uncommon.

Comment: Is there any 'readback' mechanism in the protocol?  i.e. can you ask the machine to echo back the feedrate you just sent it so that you can ensure it was correct?

Comment: Also, really really push for a firmware upgrade.  I've been working on a project where we have been living with occasional serial data dropouts (and no checksum) for years, and it has reached the point where a significant amount of time is being spent on developing solutions to detect and repair or ignore any bad records recieved.   We would have saved serious effort by just fixing the transmitter in the first place, but we never elevated the problem to a high-enough priority until it was too late.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We may not all be familiar with G-Code, a [link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G-code) is always helpful for domain specific technology.

I would say that the simple checksum is probably adequately suited to the data length, format, and the processor performance.  If you are already dropping characters, you hardly want to add more CPU load with a CRC do you?

You have multiple lines of defence in this protocol.  The data has to be well formed, in sequence, and pass a checksum, it also appears to have a fairly limited valid character set.  So checking syntax, sequence, and checksum together will likley be pretty robust.  Additionally you might check that parameter values are in bounds, and of course your UART will have basic parity checking if you choose to use it.

The problem of UART Rx register overrun is better dealt with by testing the UART's overrun flag.  UARTs invariably have hardware overrun detection, and interrupt generation on overrun error.  If your serial input is interrupt driven, then it seems likely that you are either not enabling and processing the overrun, or that perhaps you are ignoring it and treating it as a normal receive interrupt.  If you are not getting an overrun, then the problem is with the FTDI device and the data loss is occurring before it gets to the UART.  The last two paragraphs below deal with possible solutions to that problem.

What baud rate does this link run at?  In most cases if you are dropping characters on a typical UART data rate then the implementation is flawed.  You are may be switching off interrupts inappropriately for too long, doing too much work at the interrupt level, or have inappropriate interrupt priority selection. You need to fix the root cause, and not try to fix a fundamental implementation problem at the protocol level; that is intended to cope with noisy data links, not bad software.

One other possible issue is the [FTDI](http://www.ftdichip.com/) device.  I have seen issues with multiple FTDI drivers conflicting and causing data drop-outs.  The solution in that case was to use FTDI's FTClean utility to remove the drivers, and then reinstall the latest driver.  FTClean appears to be absent from their site though you can obtain it indirectly through a Google search.  FTDI's site does have a different removal tool which I guess superseded FTClean.  Do you get the same problems with are real serial port?  Also I have found USB serial devices using Prolific devices and drivers to be particularly prone to data loss, even at moderate data speeds.

Finally, I have found a number of data drop-out problems using various USB-Serial devices can be solved by "cadencing" the output.  Some devices have rather small internal buffers.  You may have noticed the character drop-outs start occurring after about 128 characters or whatever the USB device's internal buffer size may be.  Inserting short delays (say 10ms) into the data stream can solve this issue.  In this case you could simply do that at the end of each line.  Another way of 'cadencing' is to poll the transmit buffer in the PC application and wait until it is empty before adding more data, and then only adding data in small chunks, in your case a single line perhaps.  I have found that this usually solves data loss problems with no observable loss in data transfer performance.

Comment: Your points are all valid, but my question is about how to make the *driver* more robust with existing firmware.  There are at least 3 "strains" of firmware in existence and derivatives of each of those, and most people have built with custom options to match their exact configurations.  Being able to communicate robustly with the "broken" firmware is valuable.

Comment: I like the idea of strategically introducing delays - particularly if you can characterize the overruns on the MCU as being more common after bursts of data of some size. But, I think that it's being kind to say a checksum algorithm is adequate when it can't detect two dropped characters. Cripes - whoever came up with the protocol should have at least added a line length to the protocol or mixed the character positions into the checksum calculation.

Comment: Ahh, I like the idea of splitting up duplicates with delays.  At least one firmware appears to ignore control characters, so I could transmit `F30^A^A^A^A0^A^A^A0...`  I'll inspect the others for similar tricks.

Comment: @Ben:  It is not the clear what you mean by *driver*.  Do you mean the PC client application that is communicating with the embedded target?  Regarding delays, I actually mean a "delay", not dummy characters; that may only exacerbate the problem, especially if as I suspect the overrun is occurring in the FTDI device and not the microcontroller. A simple Sleep() call between messages will suffice surely?

Comment: @Michael:  You are probably right, but dropping characters is an implementation flaw not an environmental condition.  The protocol should never have had to cope with broken software.

Comment: @Clifford: I strongly suspect the MCU is at fault.  The UART interrupt is lower priority than the timer interrupt.  The timer interrupt is doing (emulated) floating point math.  The same hardware (my test system) running other firmware can handle double the baud rate.  Thus the `^A` stuffing is interesting because a single extra char adds sub-ms delay.  The aim would be to force back-to-back dropped chars to be a checksum failure.  Your sleep solution would be aimed at simply not losing bytes in the first place, but I worry that OS-granularity sleeps would kill bandwidth.

Comment: @Michael: Fair enough, but s/w floating point in an ISR!?  Who is writing this stuff? That's just incompetence.  I wonder why floating point is even necessary?

Comment: I'm accepting this answer because I think pauses (in some form) between duplicates is the most promising driver-side option for a firmware that starves the RX ISR.  (I have tested with "good" firmware and seen no drops at double the rate, so the bad checksum algorithm doesn't even come into play)

Comment: @Clifford: just in case I'm being misunderstood - I don't defend the MCU firmware implementation. Clearly, it's the real cause of the problem. I just think a protocol should could be better without being all that much more complex.  Between the two, Ben is left having to hack around both problems - if either the MCU had a sane timer ISR *or* the protocol could detect these errors, Ben would have never had to worry about the hack he's about to unleash.

Comment: @Clifford: Also to be clear - my 'protocol' comment wasn't meant to be a criticism of the overall answer (which I upvoted when I made the comment) - just stating my opinion about the link protocol.

Answer (score 5):

One thing you could try is to configure the UART on the host to send 2 stop bits instead of 1 (which is what you're probably currently using).  The MCU receiver will notice nothing except that there's an extra bit-time of idle between characters. That's about 10% more time to get the character out of the receive register before the next character is shifted in.

Typically, a UART doesn't look for more than 1 stop bit on receive data, even if the UART is configured for 2 stop bits (there's no reason to enforce extra stop bits on receive), so the fact that the MCU will still send only a single stop bit shouldn't cause any problems on receiving responses from the device.

If you're at a high data rate this doesn't add much time, so it probably won't help (but that depends on what's the underlying cause of the overruns is).  If my ciphering is right, it works out to another 25 microseconds for the MCU to avoid an overrun if you're running the link at 38400 bps.

It's a long shot, but it's a cheap change that should require no modifications other than the serial port configuration on the host side.

Answer (score 4):

If you can't change the firmware, your options are quite limited for what you can do on the PC to improve the robustness of the link. Just a few possibilities:

- Lower the data rate if the firmware allows for that (reduce chance of dropped bytes).
- Try to construct packets that don't contain zero or duplicate bytes, if the protocol or functionality has any flexibility to allow for that.
- Send messages several times (this makes it more likely the device will receive a good message; this doesn't help to reduce "false positives" however).

If you *can* change the firmware, then you have much greater potential for improvement: implement a proper CRC (even an 8-bit CRC would be a significant improvement, but 16 bits would be better).

You would be best to implement auto-negotiation in the PC driver so it can talk both the "old" and "new" protocols, and figure out which type of device it's talking to.

Comment: Lowering data rate does help but the system can be bandwidth limited (many short tool moves) so it's a tradeoff.  After making the driver robust in the face of 10% xmit failures I reached a point where "false positives" are the main danger.

Comment: Given the firmware limitation, I like the idea of attempting to construct shortest-possible packets which avoid duplicate chars.  Use the line-renumbering code to avoid cases where the line number matches the data.  I also agree that a firmware upgrade would be a better bet.